# Do I need to have a checksum if I am using GZIP?

Tags: java, sockets, gzip, checksum, gzipstream

I am using GZIP compression to send a payload via sockets.

Should I also send a md5 checksum with that or does GZIP handle the checksum for me and my checksum would just add unneeded size?

Comment: [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) includes a CRC-32 checksum as footer. Does that suffice for your needs? You may want to elaborate a little now your actual application context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gzip decompression verifies the decompressed data with both a CRC-32 and the length of the decompressed data (modulo 2^32).  So there is already a check.  If that's not strong enough for you, you can add an MD5, SHA-2, or whatever.